# Soft reset on a Cortex-M using GDB

Tags: arm, gdb, embedded, cortex-m, thumb

I'm working on a set of debugging tools for some in-house Cortex-M4 cores. I'm building embedded (no OS) ELF images using a gcc/binutils toolchain and simulating them using a modified version of QEMU. I'm creating the interrupt vector tables at the start (i.e. 0) of my images, and correctly initialising the stack pointer, and start address (i.e. the address of main).

The target programs are running as expected, and the debug tools which are built using the GDB remote protocol are working correctly.

What I'm currently trying to understand is how to initiate a soft-reset from GDB. That is, arrange for the target program to be reinitialised with the stack pointer reset to the initial value in the vector table, and the PC back at the start address.

I have already demonstrated to myself that the action of setting the PC value to 0, and running the core is not appropriate, and the result was that my "UsageFault" exception handler was invoked. (I assume that the core is in the wrong mode to execute this kind of action).

Is there a technique, i.e. by register writes using GDB remote protocol that I can soft-reset the simulated core, that is without having to power-cycle the QEMU session?

Comment: Address 0 is the initial stack pointer.

Comment: Correct. However, direct access to the SP from an application is prevented by Cortex-M in thumb mode. Since reinitialising the SP is a requirement of a SW reset, another method is required. Vik's answer below seems to be close to what is required, I just need to debug exactly what is actually when I send QEMU the memory write over GDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can make SW restart by writing `SYSRESETREQ` bit + KEY into `AIRCR` register:

```
AIRCR_REG_ADDRESS = 0xe000ed0c
AIRCR_KEY = 0x05fa0000
AIRCR_SYSRESETREQ_BIT = 0x00000004

AIRCR_REG = AIRCR_KEY | AIRCR_SYSRESETREQ_BIT
```

More info is [`here`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/Cihehdge.html)

This is working with all cortex-M

Comment: I'm trying out your suggestion. QEMU processes the write packet, but I'm unsure whether the correct action is taken.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable solution, however, currently it seems that the QEMU instance that I am using to simulate a real CPU, is not emulating the required area (the SCB) correctly.

Comment: Ok, in that case use before setting `AIRCR` also [`DEMCR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/CEGHJDCF.html) register and set bit `VC_CORERESET` (`DEMCR = 0x00000001`), this halt CPU after reset and you can look into SP, PC, ... if is correctly restarted

Comment: Ok, thanks Vik. But I think that my main problem is that QEMU is not making any of the cortexm peripherals (i.e. E0000000-E00FFFFF) visible in the memory map made accessible to GDB. I found the function (QEMU) which ignores the write attempts. So I subsequently tried directly writing to AIRCR in my target (i.e. the cortexm's application) code. But despite reaching the correct routine in QEMU to do the reset, I then found another qemu issue preventing the reset actually proceeding. I may need to raise additional questions to qemu experts.

Comment: I just tried @Vik 's suggestion of setting DEMCR=0x00000001 first in the target application just before the write of AIRCR. But it looks like a qemu issue is currently preventing further progress. I need to investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet of code for a Cortex-M3 I use to jump to any location with valid code in (including jumping to 0):

```
   IRQn_Type interrupt = (IRQn_Type)0;
   app_fn jump = *(app_fn *)(jumpaddr + sizeof(int));     //Reset is 2nd in table
   uint32_t stack_adr = *(uint32_t *)(jumpaddr);         //Stack pointer is 1st in table

   //Disable interrupts before jumping
   SysTick->CTRL &= ~ST_CTRL_ENABLE;

   while (interrupt <= CANActivity_IRQn)
   {
      NVIC_DisableIRQ(interrupt);
      interrupt++;
   }

   //Set the new stack pointer
   __set_MSP(stack_adr);

   //Set the new vector address
   SCB->VTOR = (location & 0x1FFFFF80);

   //Leap of faith!
   jump();
```

This code assumes `jumpaddr` is the base address of a vector table, as the stack pointer is first in the table and reset handler is second in the table.

Disabling interrupts is a must as you could have an interrupt go off after you have moved the stack pointer which normally causes an exception.

Of course, doing it this way will not reset any peripherals so that would need to be done before enabling the interrupts again.

**Edit:**

You can find the contents of __set_MSP [here](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_armcc.h).

Comment: I looked up __set_MSP. How do I write that code in gcc/gas for ARM? I'm curious, how does the code execution from address 0, work after the jump - I'd assumed that processor needs a mode switch first?

Comment: Not entirely sure how to write it in gcc but might be something like: `asm volatile ("msr  msp, %0": "=m" (stack_adr));`

Comment: The above code is executed in privileged mode (no OS) from a bootloader. I use [NVIC_SystemReset](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/core_cm3.h) to reset to the bootloader (at 0x00000000).

Comment: Thanks @NeRa, I'll try it next week.